# How to find stationary points of a multivariate quadratic function?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratics, hessian-matrix, stationary-point

I'm given a function
$$f = 391 x^{2} + 156 x y - 222 x z + 144 x w + 1224 x + 524 y^{2} - 156 y z - 88 y w - 2568 y + 391 z^{2} - 144 z w + 1016 z + 374 w^{2} - 1692 w$$

I find its stationary points by solving the system:

$$\begin{cases} f_{x}' = 0\\  f_{y}' = 0\\  f_{z}' = 0 \\ f_{w}' = 0 \end{cases}$$
If I'm not mistanken it has the only solution $A = (-3, 3, -1, 3)$.

Then I find the Hessian matrix that is the following:

It appears that it doesn't depend on the variables $x,y,z,w $.
$$H(x,y,z,w) = \begin{bmatrix}
  782. & 156. & -222. & 144.\\
  156. & 1048. & -156. & -88.\\
  -222. & -156. & 782. & -144.\\
  144. & -88. & -144. & 748.\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I expected that I would substitute the stationary point into Hessian and calculate some determinants not check whether it's a minimum, saddle or maximum. But all the values are constant. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix is positive definite, it is a convex quadratic function.

Hence it is the global minimum.

Remark: We don't really need to compute all the eigenvalues. For example, I can use Gershgorin's theorem to bound the eigenvalue and find that all the eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: Am I right that the clean solution would be:  
(1) find that the matrix of the initial coefficients is Positive Definite (to check that eigenvalues are positive)
(2) Calculate the first-order derivative to find the optimal point

Comment: yup, that's right